# hyperlink item in list with corresponding part in (svg) image

Tags: hyperref, labels, svg

I need to hyperlink item in list with corresponding part in (svg) image or vice-versa. Based on the available options, only page links can be added in svg image for each object; but not to specific item-label in tex file. My goal is to make the image/ text interactive in either way.

I have checked multiple solutions but none so far have this feature. tikz package as well doesn't offer hyperlinking. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to make a complete example that demonstrates your problem and can be used to test solutions.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As @Ulrike Fischer mentioned, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem with a compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`